# ng-class not updating on scroll

Tags: angularjs, sass

I want to change the background of my navigation bar depending on the users location and scroll position. Basically it will be filled if the users in on any page other than the root, and if they are on the root it will be filled if they scroll past the full height of their window (as this is the height of my header).

My angular code seems to be working in that my `console.log`'s output correctly. But the `.fill` class doesn't seem to be getting applied! Instead it only applies once the `.open` class get's applied (when the menu button is clicked), and then doesn't get removed when the user scrolls back up!.

Here's my code for my navbar directive.

```
angular.module('lumbajackApp')
  .directive('navbar', function ($location, $window) {
    return {
     templateUrl: 'app/navbar/navbar.html',
     restrict: 'EA',
     link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      var ngwindow = angular.element($window);
      var height = $window.innerHeight;
      var scrollPos = 0;

      ...omitted... 

      ngwindow.bind('resize', function(){
        height = $window.innerHeight;
      });
      scope.isFilled = false;

      if ($location.path() === '/') {
        ngwindow.bind('scroll', function(){
          scrollPos = this.pageYOffset;
          if (scrollPos > height){
            scope.isFilled = true;
            console.log(scope.isFilled);
          } else {
            scope.isFilled = false;
            console.log(scope.isFilled);
          }
        });
      } else {
        scope.isFilled = true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And here is a snippet of the html:

```
<div class="top-nav" ng-class="{'fill':isFilled, 'open':!isCollapsed}">
  ...
</div>
```

Finally, my SCSS snippet

```
/* Nav states */

.top-nav.fill {
  background: url(/assets/images/pattern2.png) repeat;
  background-size: 1000px;
}

.top-nav.open {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular digest cycle will not execute on your window.scroll.

you need to notify angular to run digest cycle for you.

After updating your scope variable, notify angular to update view. Write following line at the end of your scroll handler.

```
 scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect. Thanks's @dhavalcengg! Such a simple thing, just overlooked it :)

Comment: Yeah I will do, just have to wait 2mins before it will let me - you answered too quick bro!

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed.